# Meaning of code example

Tags: c++, function

I need to know what the following source code means:

```
scalar sumLocalContErr = runTime.deltaTValue()*
mag(contErr)().weightedAverage(mesh.V()).value();
```

What does the `*mag(contErr)()` in this connection mean? I tried to google it, but could not find an explanation.

greetings
streight

Comment: multiplying the return of two functions, maybe? And the code going after the * maybe should be on the same line. Then, that code will only multiply the return of them.

Comment: Looks like a multiplication. But we can't be sure without knowing all the types! But you really should **use a debugger** !

Comment: Unless scalar is some new primitive type, it could mean anything due to operator overloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
runTime.deltaTValue() * mag(contErr)().weightedAverage(mesh.V()).value();
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         1                                      2
```

**Expr 1:** is obvious. `runTime.deltaTValue()` calls a method and returns an object. The returned object has an overloaded `*` operator which accepts object from expression 2.

**Expr 2:** It seems `mag` is a class with a constructor which accepts `contErr`. Then `mag(contErr)` is an object. This object has an overloaded `()` operator. So, `mag(contErr)()` is a method calling. By calling it, it returns another object, which has method `weightedAverage`, this method accepts `mesh.V()` and returns an object which has method `value`.

Comment: And `*` is only for the multiplication?

Comment: @Streight: Maybe. But usually yes, it should mean a multiplication.